# How do you restore a checkbox's buttondrawable back to defaults

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I have an app, with checkboxes in an activity. In some conditions, I will set the button's drawable like this

```
checkbox.setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_selector);
```

Then I will want to restore it to the default checkbox drawable later. Setting to `null` or `0` is not correct. I can't find the default checkbox drawable in the Android resources (ie "`android:drawable/the_default_checkbox_states`"). I need to support a minimum of API 21. How do you do this ?

Comment: Have you tried with _android.R.drawable.the_default_checkbox_states_?

Comment: it is a generic reference to a non-existent resource, asking if there is a resource for this...